# get first 2 charater from an object using JS

Tags: javascript

i wanted represent first two letters of phone number,i want to get phone numbers first two characters. what i have tried is below Get first two of attribute and find target based on it.

```
    let object = [
        "key": {
               login-attempt: 1
               name: "ADMIN"
               phone: "0777123456"
            }]
```

what i have tried is below

```
object[0].substr(0,2);
```

Comment: you left out `.key` and `.phone`.

Comment: `object[0].key.phone.substr(0, 2)`

Comment: @Barmar, that should probably be an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: I'd rather close the question.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let test = {
        key: {
               "login-attempt": 1,
               name: "ADMIN",
               phone: "0777123456",
          }
     };
            
console.log(test.key.phone.substr(0,2));
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

You're more likely to have an object like this:

```
let object = {
  login-attempt: 1
  name: "ADMIN"
  phone: "0777123456"
};
```

In this case, your code might be:

```
let prefix = object.phone.substr(0,2);
```

Or you might have an array of objects:

```
let object = [
  {
    login-attempt: 1
    name: "ADMIN"
    phone: "0777123456"
  },
  {
    login-attempt: 1
    name: "CLERK"
    phone: "2222222222"
  }
];
```

You can get the 1st two characters of the second element like this:

```
let prefix = object[1].phone.substr(0,2);
```

If the element was nested within "key":

```
let object = {
  key: {
    login-attempt: 1
    name: "ADMIN"
    phone: "0777123456"
  }
};

let prefix = object.key.phone.substr(0,2);
```

And so on...